# Creating Table with Relationship and Inserting Data using Mongodb in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have two tables Abc and Xyz. Abc and Xyz have a relationship. Abc has x_id(foreign key from Xyz table). How can I achieve this in Mongodb? I have tried doing this::

a. abc.rb(model)

```
class Abc
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :name
  has_one :xyz
end
```

b. xyz.rb(model)

```
Class Xyz
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :name
  belongs_to :abc
end
```

Is this the correct way of establishing or mapping one to one(or many) relationships in mongodb?

Now, how to insert data on these tables? For eg: I need to insert 'test' as name in abc and 'test_test' as name in xyz. And insert id(or anything that creates relationship between these two tables) of xyz having name 'test_test' on abc.

Comment: Take a look at the [data model patterns](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/) for some ideas about how to model relationships in MongoDB. The go-to solution shouldn't be foreign keys and all that relational jazz. The right path depends on your use case.

Comment: @wdberkeley I have gone through the above link. I understood also, but got issue on implementing. How to insert data on these table? How to implement one to many relationship?

Comment: The point is there isn't a single right way to implement one to many relationships. There's a good collection of [blog posts](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) making this point that hopefully have some good advice for your use case.